How to correctly interpolate a variable in a JavaScript template literal for a URL in Oracle APEX?
I’m trying to construct a URL in Oracle APEX JavaScript using a template literal, but I’m running into an issue where the variable isn’t being interpolated correctly. Instead of getting the expected URL, the variable name is becoming weired.
Here’s what I’m doing:
In Execute when Page Loads Section:
const test = `url("f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE:NO::IMAGE_ID:1745")`;
console.log(test);

For this I get the working URL as following:
url("/ords/r/pj/employee-self-service-portal/home?image_id=1745&request=APPLICATION_PROCESS%3DGETIMAGE&session=890152562441&cs=12Y_buvBPIPUg6fQgAiURQM6QvOyCwIKjlcewXmOTiJMfdOkwT0QubRWuzmRHaSAuwXBtH4iDjQl1YMNWm72OXw")

But know I want to use a variable instead of Hardcoded 1745
For example:
const imageId = 1745;
const test = `url("f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE:NO::IMAGE_ID:${1745}")`;
console.log(test);

This results in:
url("/ords/r/pj/employee-self-service-portal/home?image_id=%24%7BimageId%7D&request=APPLICATION_PROCESS%3DGETIMAGE&session=890152562441&cs=1dtlavkb6EP2nlZk9_KxMOcV6GSGzUTtKOAYodnsYe-DshAwwwSIr-pVAqpEb82XGSIHELUFeWMdJxKc5LrrAJQ")

The Variable is not Set
The AJAX Process is as Follows (An Application process)
DECLARE
  l_lob     BFILE;
  v_pic     blob;
  l_length  NUMBER;
BEGIN
--
select picture into v_pic from pjpayroll.hremp WHERE pkcode = :IMAGE_ID ; --461;

  l_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength(v_pic);
  htp.flush;
  htp.init;
  htp.p('Content-length: ' || l_length);
  htp.p('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="&REQUEST."');
  owa_util.http_header_close;
  wpg_docload.download_file(v_pic);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;

What I am Trying to build is an Organization Chart usinf third party d3.OrgChart Library
Following is the Javascript code
var chart;
function fetchDataAndShowAlert() {
    d3.csv(
        '#APP_FILES#TEST.csv'
      ).then((dataFlattened) => {
        chart = new d3.OrgChart()
          .container('.t-Body-mainContent')
          .data(dataFlattened)
          .nodeHeight((d) => 85)
          .nodeWidth((d) => {
            return 220;
          })
          .childrenMargin((d) => 50)
          .compactMarginBetween((d) => 25)
          .compactMarginPair((d) => 50)
          .neightbourMargin((a, b) => 25)
          .siblingsMargin((d) => 25)
          .buttonContent(({ node, state }) => {
            return `<div style="px;color:#716E7B;border-radius:5px;padding:4px;font-size:10px;margin:auto auto;background-color:white;border: 1px solid #E4E2E9"> <span style="font-size:9px">${
              node.children
                ? `<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>`
                : `<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>`
            }</span> ${node.data._directSubordinates}  </div>`;
          })
          .linkUpdate(function (d, i, arr) {
            d3.select(this)
              .attr('stroke', (d) =>
                d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? '#152785' : '#E4E2E9'
              )
              .attr('stroke-width', (d) =>
                d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? 5 : 1
              );

            if (d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted) {
              d3.select(this).raise();
            }
          })
          .nodeContent(function (d, i, arr, state) {
            const color = '#FFFFFF';
            return `
            <div style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;background-color:${color}; position:absolute;margin-top:-1px; margin-left:-1px;width:${d.width}px;height:${d.height}px;border-radius:10px;border: 1px solid #E4E2E9">
               <div style="background-color:${color};position:absolute;margin-top:-25px;margin-left:${15}px;border-radius:100px;width:50px;height:50px;" ></div>
               <img src="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE:NO::IMAGE_ID:1745" style="position:absolute;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:${20}px;border-radius:100px;width:40px;height:40px;" />
              <div style="font-size:15px;color:#08011E;margin-left:20px;margin-top:32px"> ${
                d.data.name
              } </div>
              <div style="color:#716E7B;margin-left:20px;margin-top:3px;font-size:10px;"> ${
                d.data.positionName
              } </div>
           </div>`;
          })
          .render();
      })
}


This works but everyone have Image of 1745 id. I want to make it dynamic by instead of 1745, passing value from d.data.id.
Looking Forward  for responses.

${1745} should be ${imageId}

It still does not work

I see very little relationship between your template literal and the resulting string.

It is  in Oracle APEX environment. It Automatically adds sessions and all thhe extra stuff

I'm not familiar with that, but I don't see how it can affect console.log(test).

Do You Belive it has to do something with encoding?

Anything is possible, but that doesn't seem likely. Digits don't have any special encoding.

If the value of test is the same, it should be processed the same by Oracle APEX.

There are 2 options for this, both of them require a server side call. If the page requires a checksum (strongly advised) then it is not possible to generate the url using javascript. The url needs to be generated in the database.

If it is on "execute when page loads" then you could use a before rendering page process or computation calling the APEX_PAGE.GET_URL pl/sql API. This will ensure that the checksum is calculated correctly?

-or -

Use javascript and generate the url using an Ajax callback process defined in the apex page (can also be at application level)

However, please take a step back and explain the business requirement. It's not because you picked Javascript as a solution that this is the best option - maybe you could just use a data attribute (with that variable "imageId ") in the chart and generate the url in a dynamic action on click.
One option is to create a sample on apex.oracle.com and post the login details here so someone can have a look.

I have Edited my Question adding the actual code. Hopefully my problem is more clear.

As others have commented shortly after you posted, it should be ${imageId}  not ${1745}. Your updated question still has ${1745}. Have you tried changing it ? It will not work if your page has checksums because in that case a url cannot be constructed using javascript as I said. I'd go for my option 2.

src="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE:NO::IMAGE_ID:${d.data.id}"

I made the page unrestricted and updated the src. It still do not make the url righ

If you create your test case on apex.oracle.com I'm happy to have a look.
